# How to get rid of a filter coming from another Table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

i can't find the correct DAX expression to allow the calculation of my measure "Conso A LAST Relevé -1" when i select a row in the "Choose TABLE".
Indeed, it applies a SELECTEDVALUE(EDV[Ordre TimeLine]) filter to the "Result TABLE" but my measure needs to be calculated with  SELECTEDVALUE(EDV[Ordre TimeLine]) - 1.
As a matter of facts, the Result Table can't find this value, thus nos result appears.

Can someone help me with this  pb ?
Thanks in advance

[link to my Pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8DItDJyZUh7kqK90?e=TlkCdB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ALL(...)`, `REMOVEFILTERS(...)`, `ALLEXCEPT(...)`, and a few others. In your case, use `REMOVEFILTERS(...)`.

```
CALCULATE(
    [Conso A],
    REMOVEFILTERS(EDV[Date & Heure], EDV[Duration], EDV[Fluide]),
    EDV[Ordre TimeLine] = _ChoixR - 1
)
```

You have to remove each of the columns in the Choose table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using ALL returns a global value for all the rows of Result TABLE whereas i want a result for each row of the result TABLE.

Comment: See updated answer above

Comment: Awesome and understood ! So great... Thanks very much for your help.